I get either unauthorized or forbidden when trying to login with a user from the database using spring security
I am trying to learn spring security. I followed a tutorial on how to secure your application. Unfortunately some of the things he added were deprecated and I tried replacing the deprecated functions. The program works well with users that are created and saved in memory but when I tried adding users to the database and authenticate with them I encounter either unauthorized 401 if I have the httpBasic() in the filter chain or forbidden 403 if I deleted it.
Here is my SecurityConfig class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final CustomizedUserDetailsService customizedUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).authenticated();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

Login Method:
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody RegisterDTO loginDto){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginDto.getUsername(),
                        loginDto.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User logged in successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

CustomizedUserDetialsService:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomizedUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, CustomizedUserDetailsService {
    private final UserEntityRepository repository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = repository.findByusername(username)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("user doesn't exist in our database."));
        return new User(username, user.getPassword(), mapToGrantedAuthority(user.getRoles()));
    }
    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> mapToGrantedAuthority(List<Role> roles){
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getAuthority())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserPresent(String username){
        return repository.existsByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity saveUser(UserEntity user) {
        return repository.save(user);
    }
}

I can provide the register method too or any other class that you want but I don't want to make this question longer than it is. Last thing it would be great if anyone can suggest a beginner friendly source for learning spring security. Thank you!

Can't help you with the question at hand but here is a resource I used to learn security. https://auth0.com/blog/spring-boot-authorization/

It's very much appreciated. Thank you! @DanielHernández

Pls refer
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/index.html#publish-authentication-manager-bean
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/user-details-service.html#servlet-authentication-userdetailsservice
You need to define CustomizedUserDetailsService as bean and set it in the authenticationManager.
There is no need for @RequiredArgsConstructor

The problem was that I didn't provide a default constructor in my User entity.
